# Infinite scrolling in both horizontal and vertical direction - Nextjs

Tags: next.js, infinite-scroll, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I wanna implement an infinite vertical and horizontal scrollable container to display a carousel of images in a nextjs project. Is there some way to achieve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apply tailwind css to your project. And use overflow-x, overflow-y and container to the div tag that contains the images.

https://tailwindcss.com/